# Intellij IDEA - Generate (Alt + Insert)

Tags: intellij-idea

1. Place my cursor on some class variable.
2. Click **Alt + Insert**
3. In **Generate** popup choose **Getter & Setter**
4. Getter & Setter are generated on above the variable.

**Question:** How to make Getter & Setter appears on the bottom of the class?

Comment: Put your cursor where you want them to be generated (e.g at the bottom of the .java source).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't have a facility to allow getters/setters to be generated at the bottom of the class.  You would have to place your cursor at the bottom of the class file (or wherever you wanted it) before generating getters and setters.

Answer (score 4):

Does the [rearrange entries](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/) stuff do what you want?
Not used it myself, but it seems like it's meant to do exactly what you want (if it doesn't, consider raising a feature request).

Though I usually do it like duffymo said in his comment on your question.  It's worth noting that you can generate multiple getter/setter methods at a time (just select multiple fields in the popup).

[image]