# Insert Getter / Setter at end of file with IntelliJ IDEA (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, getter-setter

When I generate Getter and Setter using IntelliJ IDEA with `Alt` + `Insert` --> `Getter and Setter`, they are inserted above my cursor.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ insert them at the end of the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone asked that before.
That's not possible.

See: [Intellij IDEA - Generate (Alt + Insert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392673/intellij-idea-generate-alt-insert)

Old question/answer, but I couldn't find it in IDEA 14 (Community) either.

Comment: And when you don't have Insert key? My keyboard doesn't have Insert key and I can't use "And + Insert" for "Generate" shortcut

Comment: @davidleongz go to the "Code" menu and select "Generate..."